# Выбор конкретного значения из одинаковых элементов с помощью jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице есть следующие элементы.

```html
<select>
    <option>1a</option>
    <option>2a</option>
    </select>
<ul>
  <li>1a</li>
</ul>
<select>
    <option>1b</option>
    <option>2b</option>
    </select>
<ul>
  <li>1b</li>
</ul>
<select>
    <option>1c</option>
    <option>2c</option>
    </select>
<ul>
  <li>1c</li>
</ul>
```

**Суть задачи в следующем**:

В элемент `li` должно подставляться выбранное в `select` значение (как в коде: в данном случае по умолчанию выбрано первое значение). Причем даже по умолчанию, при загрузке страницы, в `li` должно быть значение из `select`. Для каждого `select` есть свой `li`. 
Вся проблема заключается в том, чтобы получить нужное мне значение. Делая так, как сейчас, я получаю все выбранные элементы со всех `select`.

```
$val = $('select option:selected').text();
```

Причем у `select` нет каких-то отличительных значений, атрибутов. 
Подскажите, как поступить? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы выбирать рядомстоящие элементы, используйте методы `.next()` и `.prev()`.

```js
$('ul').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).prev('select').find('option:selected').text(); // выбираем предшествующий select, находим в нем выбранную опцию и берем из нее текст
  $(this).find('li').text(text); // вставляем полученный текст в li
});

$('select').on('change', function() { // при выборе опции
  var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text(); // находим выбранную опцию и берем из нее текст
  $(this).next('ul').find('li').text(text); // выбираем идущий следом ul, в нем находим li и вставляем в него полученный текст
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option>1a</option>
<option>2a</option>
</select>
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<select>
<option>1b</option>
<option>2b</option>
</select>
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<select>
<option>1c</option>
<option>2c</option>
</select>
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Кто минусует, хотя бы пишите за что.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Cheg в 98% случаев никто не скажет почему) иногда это просто так)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский видимо, такой способ самовыражаться...

Comment: @Cheg когда как. но и отчитываться тоже никто не обязан. увы, несовершенство системы ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это да